# Portable format for UML models

Tags: uml

Is there a portable format for UML diagrams, such that such a diagram saved in that format can be imported and rendered by any, or nearly any, modeling tool?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Metadata_Interchange says "At the moment there are several incompatibilities between different modeling tool vendor implementations of XMI, even between interchange of abstract model data. The usage of Diagram Interchange is almost nonexistent. Unfortunately this means exchanging files between UML modeling tools using XMI is rarely possible." That would seem to suggest the answer is no, unless there is some other format that is used instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no.  Longer answer is partially.  XMI is portable regarding elements, etc. Fonts, location on diagram, etc. not so much.  Which is pretty much what you already knew.

Comment: There is a specification from the OMG called Diagram Definition, which includes Diagram Interchange. So far, only Papyrus implements it. Other vendors are working on it.

Comment: On the other hand, and being a bit cynical, the commercial vendors for which I worked int the past (disclaimer: I now work on Papyrus) did not have a big incentive to facilitate their customers moving to other tools by providing this capability... This can certainly be seen in the level of participation and activity in the "interop" working groups both at OMG and INCOSE... It's nice to say "we're working on it", it's another to actually provide the capability - which is why there are also many tool-specific importers.